# jQuery compare and append

Tags: jquery, compare, append

I have a drop down that I check with jquery and if a certain value is selected then an input box is revealed. I need to compare the selected value with an array and if the selection matches one of the values in the array then the value must be added to my hidden field's tag. Advice would be very much appreciated since my jquery knowledge is next to none

My current code: 
(I will query my database to get all the child values of trekkers and that will be my array)

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
        jQuery(function ($){
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    $(".kw").hide();
                });

            $(function(){
                $('.postform').change(function() {
                    var selectData = $(this).attr("data-select");
                    var selectValue = $(this).val();
                    $('.kw').hide();
                     if($("fieldset[data-select='" + selectData + selectValue +"']").css("display") == "none"){
                         $("fieldset[data-select^='" + selectData + "']").hide();
                         $("fieldset[data-select='" + selectData + selectValue +"']").show();
                     }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>

<form role="search" method="get" id="equipfilter" action="">
 <fieldset>
  <select name="exc_equipment_cat" id="exc_equipment_cat" class="postform" data-select="select1">
    <option class="level-0" value="allerlei">Allerlei&nbsp;&nbsp;(10)</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="implemente">Implemente&nbsp;&nbsp;(97)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="balers-toebehore">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Balers &amp; Toebehore&nbsp;&nbsp;(4)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="disse">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Disse&nbsp;&nbsp;(4)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="hammermeule">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hammermeule&nbsp;&nbsp;(4)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="ploee">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ploeë&nbsp;&nbsp;(11)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="ripper">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ripper&nbsp;&nbsp;(8)</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="trekkers">Trekkers&nbsp;&nbsp;(43)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="case">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Case&nbsp;&nbsp;(4)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="fiat">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fiat&nbsp;&nbsp;(5)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="ford">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ford&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="john-deere">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;John Deere&nbsp;&nbsp;(13)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="landini">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Landini&nbsp;&nbsp;(5)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="massey-ferguson">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Massey Ferguson&nbsp;&nbsp;(3)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="mccormick">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;McCormick&nbsp;&nbsp;(4)</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="new-holland">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;New Holland&nbsp;&nbsp;(8)</option>
 </select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="kw" data-select="select1 WHERE VALUE SHOULD BE ADDED" style="display: none;">
  <legend>Kw Range:</legend>
  <input type="text" name="kw_min" placeholder="min" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" name="kw_max" placeholder="max" value="">
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Price Range:</legend>
  <input type="text" name="pr_min" placeholder="from" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" name="pr_max" placeholder="to" value="">
 </fieldset>
<input type="submit" id="filtersubmit" value="Search">
</form>
```

This is in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13526454/1846934)

Comment: post some existing code please

Comment: I added my existing code. I have the hide option working if I use a test value. My array will be populated by querying my database using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this helps you

```
var values = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
jQuery('your-selector-to-select').change(function(){
    var j = jQuery(this);
    if(values.indexOf(j.val()) >= 0) {
        jQuery('hidden-selector').val(j.val());
    }
});
```

answer to your first question:

```
jQuery('your-fieldset-selector').attr('data-select', 'select1 ' + j.val());
```

Comment: how do I append my value to `<fieldset class="kw" data-select="select1 WHERE VALUE SHOULD BE ADDED" style="display: none;">`

Comment: I need to keep the select1 and then add my j.val currently it replaces the select1

Comment: I can kiss you :-), work 100% now I just need to learn how to transfer an array from php to jquery

Answer (score 0):

using inArray(value,array) to search in array and get matched index .

```
var yourarray = ['value1','value2'];
$('.matchedindex').text($.inArray($('.search').val(),yourarray) ;
```

if `$('.search').val()` was equal to value1 then `$('.matchedindex').text()` will be 1

or you can use $.each for searching in array :

```
var flag=false;
$.each(array,function(i,value){
    if(value.search($('.search').val())!=-1){
    # search is matched # you have index and value of array
        flag=true;
    }
});
```